# regex for splitting key value-pair containing comma

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I need a regex to split key-value pairs.Key and value are separated by =
Values can contain comma(,) but if they contain comma(,) they need to be enclosed by ("").Also the value in ("") can contain multiple inner ("") with comma(,) in them.Hence multiple level of nesting with (" , ") is possible.

Key can anything except ( comman(,) equal(=)  double quote("") )

Example- abc="hi my name is "ayush,nigam"",def="i live at "bangalore",ghi=bangalore is in karnataka,jkl="i am from UP"

Another example -  "ayush="piyush="abc,def",bce="asb,dsa"",aman=nigam"

I expect output as ayush="piyush="abc,def",bce="asb,dsa"" and aman=nigam

I am using the following regex code in java.

```
   Pattern abc=Pattern.compile("([^=,]*)=((?:\"[^\"]*\"|[^,\"])*)");
   String text2="AssemblyName=(foo.dll),ClassName=\"SomeClassanotherClass=\"a,b\"\"";
   Matcher m=abc.matcher(text2);

   while(m.find()) {
       String kvPair = m.group();
       System.out.println(kvPair);
  }
```

I am getting folliwng kvPair
:

AssemblyName=(foo.dll)

ClassName="SomeClassanotherClass="a

Where as i need to get,

AssemblyName=(foo.dll)

ClassName="SomeClassanotherClass="a,b"

Hence comma(,) in inner double quotes("") are not being parse properly.Please help.

Comment: Try [this approach](https://ideone.com/umlGTt), with `"([^\"=,]*)=(\".*?\"|[^,]*)(?=,[^\"=,]*=|$)"`.

Comment: It will work for this case but if multiple comma separated inner quotes are there it will still fail.Take example "ayush=\"piyush=\"abc,def\",bce=\"asb,dsa\"\",aman=nigam"; I expect ayush="piyush="abc,def",bce="asb,dsa"" and
aman=nigam

Comment: Please provide clear requirements for the value part. I see that the value may also contain a `\w+=` pattern, so we cannot rely on that, and that makes your question even more unclear.

Comment: Updated with the test case.Also key can only contain alphabets.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: You have only provided examples that are hard to deduce **requirements** from.  Try https://ideone.com/nnl4RR, but again, this is based on my own assumptions. Until you provide exact rules, no one can help you.